# Sustainable packaging for electronics and PCBs

Tags: esd, materials, antistatic, static

As an electronics engineer, I design and have lots of PCBs contract manufactured. Every supplier I have ever used will always use packaging materials like PE foam pouches and bubble wrap. Some use the pink anti-static bubble wrap. Others wing it with the standard transparent stuff. Both seem to work OK. Haven't noticed any yield issues either way.

I want to come at this from an ecological sustainability angle. What materials would be suitable replacements for these horrible, non-recyclable plastics? I'm thinking of putting in place some company-wide green supply chain policies to insist on all suppliers only using paper based or otherwise compostable materials.

What are the best options available? I've looked at paper, but it's uncertain whether standard brown kraft has suitable antistatic properties. That's about the only alternative I've found so far. This is a **really** important issue for us electrical and electronics engineers, but as far as I can see not one that's getting enough attention.

Comment: Not really an electrical engineering question per se but there is a lot of anti-static cardboard packaging out there.  Supposedly the coating is non-toxic and biodegradable.  Unsure about the recyclability, but it's a big step up from plastic.

Comment: Thanks @vir for the comment. Do you have some links to the materials you reference? I think this is electrical engineering. I believe that as engineers, we need to climb out of our little silos and start taking responsibility and pride in our profession from end to end. I don't think we should have to defer to anyone when it comes to deciding the relative merits of process & logistical decisions anywhere in the design and manufacturing cycle. After all these can be dramatically impactful on the successful delivery of our vision.

Comment: could try actual popcorn ... might cause rodent issue though

Comment: @vir I've asked a family member who works in the paper industry about such packaging and apparently it can be thrown in for recycling just like any other cardboard.

Comment: I doubt brown kraft paper is ESD safe, but you might be able to use BLACK paper.... Most black inks are carbon-based, which also makes them slightly conductive.  And slightly conductive is often good enough for ESD protection.   Why not just ask the PCB assembly house if they have options????

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure recyclable packaging is necessarily all that good for the environment. If air shipment is the norm then the extra weight of inferior perforated kraft paper and tissue paper (Digikey's standard) compared to sealed air plastic pouches will have a very significant penalty. For example, shipping an extra 100g of packing material by air from Shenzhen to Toronto emits an extra 650g+ of carbon from fuel consumption. That kind of calculation should be done if you're concerned about actual impact rather than virtue signaling. Also, plastic bags are considered recyclable here (the relevant agency asks they be gathered and put in one T-shirt bag).

By the way, there are clear bags which claim similar static dissipative properties to the 'pink' variety and give a good view of the contents, so the use of clear bags is not an indication they are being cavalier about ESD protection.

Ordinary cardboard is not a good thing to have in close contact with things that have to be solderable later- there's sulfur and formaldehyde in it that can cause corrosion. And, of course, for moisture sensitive parts sealed bags and dessicant pouches are necessary to prevent the necessity of baking later.

If your goods are used in any kind of high reliability or safety critical application, guaranteed protection from ESD damage has to take precedence. Sometimes damage can be subtle and cause later failures, hence the high importance placed on it in aerospace applications. Even in consumer applications, a small increase in customer returns and warranty repairs can end up costing a lot.

Comment: Very valid points... 1) PCBs will be supplied in plastic wrap with desiccant. That's outside my control, and not the major concern. So soldering not a problem but thanks for the heads up. I was not aware of those concerns. 2) And with environment genuinely in mind, I 100% agree with your point and do use sea shipment. 3) I also receive injection moulded cases and glass panels in foam pouches. In these cases, I feel there really is no excuse for not migrating to paper and it doesn't even need to be antistatic - I didn't want to focus on this as it is less directly relevant to electronics.

Comment: Sounds good. For the cases, I'd be concerned about abrasive paper blemishing the surface, which soft polyethylene won't do. At least here in the West people are really fussy about things like that. I'm reminded of Henry Ford who had engines shipped in crates that could be recycled as floorboards. Maybe they could ship the moldings in boxes that could be fitted with printed sleeves as the product box. Just a wild suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

There’s demand for this, so there appears to be supply. One that I found: https://www.azom.com/article.aspx?ArticleID=20028

Answer (score 0):

Moisture absorption thru paper and other materials over time is only a real problem when elevated to solder reflow or wave reflow temperatures.

The result can be [**measling**](https://www.pcbdirectory.com/community/what-is-pcb-measling) and **[crazing](https://www.google.com/search?q=crazing%20pcb&client=ms-google-coop&cx=004559422991973750901:xdgkv-korru&sxsrf=APq-WBve-Nqd4qNBiLj5VjcY-fpWlfI_IA:1651107466973&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix5rfQxrX3AhXEHc0KHfqhDxkQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1202&bih=939&dpr=1)** which are two faults that one might disqualify a supplier for if they knew the packaging and storage was acceptable.

PE wrapping is good for moisture blockage. Alternatives must be researched, evaluated and rated.

If you know you are going to consume them rapidly, you might validate less costly materials that reduce moisture influx and are biodegradable.  You may research the absorption rate and find it only affects the outer surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Anything conductive will do. Aluminum foil works great - reusable and recyclable, zero waste material. Wrap the PCB in the foil, and stick it in whatever other packaging you want. Cellulose fiber padded envelopes work fine, and can be reused many times, although aren't the lightest of packaging materials. Then stick it into a box for shipping, add spacers, put into another box so there's space between the two, and voila.